# Study the convergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac{x\ln x}{x^4-1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Study the convergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac{x\ln x}{x^4-1} dx$

So first we have two potentially problematic points which are $1,\infty$

We split the integral to $$\int_1^2 \frac{x\ln x}{x^4-1} dx + \int_2^\infty \frac{x\ln x}{x^4-1} dx$$

Now first I tried to study $I_1 = \int_1^2 \frac{x\ln x}{x^4-1} dx$.

I evaluated $\lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{x\ln x}{x^4-1} = \frac{1}{4}$ so basically the function is "nice" at $x=1$ and we can evaluate the integral, but how exactly?

I tried various of methods without luck (integration by parts , substituting $t=\ln x$ , $(x^4 - 1) = (x^2-1)(x^2+1)$ , $(x^4-1) = (x-1)(1+x+x^2+x^3)$)

**EDIT**
Following the answer I got, I thought about:

Since $\frac{x\ln(x)}{x^4-1}$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$ then we can use the inequality:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{x\ln(x)}{x^4-1} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\ln(n)}{n^4-1} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^4-1} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^4} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \lt \infty$$

Comment: You don't need to compute the exact value of the integral to study its convergence.

Comment: Letting $x=\dfrac1t$ , this becomes the derivative of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) with regard to one of its parameters, expressible in terms of the [trigamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function).

Comment: In general, for positive $n>k$ we have $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{x^n-1}~\ln x~dx~=~\frac1{n^2}~\psi_1\bigg(1-\frac kn\bigg)$.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem asks "Study the convergence", you're not required to find a closed form. Once you know the function is "nice" at $1$, you're done with that part: $I_1$ exists.  Next look at $I_2$, and again don't worry about finding a formula for it, just whether or not it converges.

By the way, the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ happens to be $\pi^2/32$, but again you are **not** expected to find that.  The integrals from $1$ to $2$ and $2$ to $\infty$ are much more complicated, involving the dilog function.

Comment: Thank you Robert, what do you think about my alternative approach? (Edited my question).

Comment: How do you know it's monotonic?

Answer (score 1):

For showing, that $I_{2}$ converges, you might use  $\ln(x)\leq x$, which is valid for $x>0$.